# WWII - documents on turn around point in German Foreign strategy - "stop we are not going to pass Finland to USSR"

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, soviet-union, finland

I want to find the turn around point in German Foreign strategy: 
ok we leave Finland to USSR - stop we would not do it. In documents.

Some of them are there:

https://archive.org/search.php?query=Documents%20on%20German%20Foreign%20Policy%20-%20Series%20D

But I need Vol 10 and it is absent. May be we have more consistent archive on specialized sites?

Comment: So you're asking where you can find a copy of "Documents on German Foreign Policy - Series D Volume X" ?

Comment: I do not know do we have other editions or other document publications for this period (on German?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [this (PDF)](https://histdoc.net/pdf/Series%20D,vol10,List.pdf) what you are looking for?

[image]

I found it as part of [this collection](https://histdoc.net/history/German_diplomacy%201939-1941.html) using the search string (without the quotes)

```
"documents on German foreign policy series d"
```

> Historical document collection: Documents on German Foreign Policy
>
> Lists of documents in Documents on German Foreign Policy, Series D, volumes VIII-XIII (The War Years), published by the US Department of State and British Government in 1954, 1956, 1957, 1961, 1962, 1954
>
> Series D, vol VIII (Sept. 4, 1939-March 18, 1940) List of Documents.pdf    *
>   Series D, vol IX (March 18-June 22, 1940) List of Documents.pdf (New PDF-version)
>   Series D, vol X (June 23-August 31,1940) List of Documents.pdf
>   Series D, vol XI (Sept.1, 1940-Jan. 1, 1941) List of documents.pdf
>   Series D, vol XII (Feb.1-June 22,1941) List of Documents.pdf    *
>   Series D, vol XIII (June 23-Dec. 11, 1941) List of Documents.pdf    *
>
> - The entire book can be found on the Net by using search engines
>
> The German versions of the entire books are published as "Akten zur deutschen auswärtigen Politik, serie D, Band 8-13". They are available on-line in [Digi20 collection](http://digi20.digitale-sammlungen.de/).

[image]

Comment: This is only analytical part... No content... But still thank you. Much better than nothing.